# Combine two images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, canvas

I'm trying to combine two images from two different URLs to form one that looks like this:
[image: Example]

Vanilla JS or any node library can be used. I have no experience with images in code so i'm not really sure what i'm looking for, but it would be greatly appreciated if an example is provided. The rough pseudo-code might look like this:

```
img1 = getImage("url")
img2 = getImage("url")

newImg = mask(img1, img2, args)

return newImg //can be a Buffer, local path, or URL
```

*Edit*: I'm looking for this to run in Node, as in without interacting with a DOM.

Comment: You can call imagemagick from Node.js, can you? And there https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#clip-mask

Comment: @c-smile How would I translate that into command into Javascript? I think this is what i'm looking for but I don't know how to use it

Comment: do you need it to work inside a browser or inside node?

Comment: @TonyRaoulIscaros Node

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is probably a easier way to this but I hope it helps.

```
    var img1 = new Image();
    var img2 = new Image();
    img1.src = "img1.jpg";
    img2.src = "img2.jpg";
    function imgMask(){ /*call this when both images loaded */
        var combied_imgs = combine(imgToData(img1),imgToData(img2));
        var img3 = dataToImg(combied_imgs);
        document.body.append(img3);
    }

    function imgToData(img){ /* Extract imgdata from img */
        var c=document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        c.width = img.width;
        c.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        return ctx.getImageData(0,0,c.width,c.height);
    }

    function combine(a,b){ /* your masking argument */
        var c = a;
        var ratio =  img1.width/img1.height;
        for (var i = 0; i < a.data.length; i++) {
            var y = (i/4)/c.width;
            var x = (i/4)%c.width; 
            if (x > y*ratio)
                c.data[i] = a.data[i];
            else
                c.data[i] = b.data[i];
        }
        return c;
    }
    function dataToImg(a){ /*img from imgdata */
        var c=document.createElement("canvas");
        c.width = a.width;
        c.height = a.height;
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.putImageData(a,0,0);
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = c.toDataURL();
        return img;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following solution using Canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var myVar = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img1 = loadImage('anyURL1.png', myFunction);
var img2 = loadImage('anyURL2.jpg', myFunction);

var numberOfImages = 0;
function myFunction() {
    numberOfImages += 1;

    if(numberOfImages == 2) {
        myVar.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

        myVar.globalAlpha = 0.5;
        myVar.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
    }
}

function loadImage(src, onload) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = onload;
    img.src = src;
    return img;
}
```

Comment: That will blend two images but TS needs masking I guess.

Comment: This is a hint. Using canvas `drawImage` he can exactly place two images according to his desire.

Comment: Two problems with this solution. The first is that i'm working with a node.js canvas, not an HTML file so I have to use node's way of generating one which i'm still figuring out. Secondly, this does in fact merge the images together and looks this [this](https://jsfiddle.net/uqzqo9er/).